# Remove keys from HashMap by passing a List of keys - Java API method or Utility for the same?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I have a `Map<String, String> issueMap` with n values

and An `ArrayList<String>` with m values, such that m is subset of n

I want to remove all these m keys from issueMap is there a direct API call for this

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can remove the keys from the `keySet` :

```
issueMap.keySet().removeAll(listOfKeysToRemove);
```

`keySet` returns a `Set` of the keys contained in the `Map`, which is backed by the `Map`. Therefore, changes to the `Map` are reflected in the `Set` and vice-versa.

[Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet--):

> Set keySet()
>
> Returns a Set view of the keys contained in this map. The set is backed by the map, so **changes to the map are reflected in the set, and vice-versa**. If the map is modified while an iteration over the set is in progress (except through the iterator's own remove operation), the results of the iteration are undefined. **The set supports element removal, which removes the corresponding mapping from the map, via the Iterator.remove, Set.remove, removeAll, retainAll, and clear operations**. It does not support the add or addAll operations.

Returns:
    a set view of the keys contained in this map